# Doesn't the option dtype (pandas) add the names of the columns directly from the keys of this dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

When loading data to create a pandas data frame and specifying dtypes in advances with a dictionary, why the keys of this dictionary are not used directly as the names of the columns?

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/filename',
                 sep='\t', 
                 index_col=False,
                 dtype={'col1':str,
                        'col2':int,
                         ... })
print(df.columns)
Index(["aa",11])
```

There are many columns and I don't want to put again a long list with the names of the columns.

I want to name the columns as is the order of my dictionary. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the walrus operator `:=` to give a name (such as `the_dtype`) to the dict you pass as the `dtype` argument and reuse it to set the `names` argument by calling `the_dtype.keys()`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./foo_dtype_test.txt',
                 sep='\t', 
                 index_col=False,
                 dtype=(the_dtype := {'col1':str,
                        'col2':int}), names=the_dtype.keys())
print(df)
```

Walrus operator is available in version 3.8; for earlier versions you can do this instead:

```py
the_dtype = {'col1':str,
    'col2':int}
df = pd.read_csv('./foo_dtype_test.txt',
                 sep='\t', 
                 index_col=False,
                 dtype=the_dtype, names=the_dtype.keys())
```

Input file foo_dtype_test.txt contains:

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0    1     2
1    3     4
2    5     6
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the assignment syntax is available on Python 3.8+ only. Python 3.7 is still very common (if not the most common) version out there.

Comment: @Quang Hoang Thanks, I've updated my answer to provide an alternative if Python version doesn't support walrus operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an OrderedDict and extract the keys for the name field (the OrderedDict is useful because you can be guaranteed that the keys-value pairs will be extracted in the order you expect)

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

x = OrderedDict({'col1': str, 'col2': int})
          
df = pd.read_csv('path/filename',
                 sep='\t', 
                 index_col=False,
                 dtype = x, 
                 names = x.keys())
```

Comment: No need to use `OrderedDict` here as regular dict will work, as "Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order" as of Python 3.7 (according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict))

Comment: Aha! Good to know @constantstranger. However, assumes 3.7 -- the question was just tagged `Python`, so I kept `OrderedDict` to be sure...as much as I love these new features, they can be a pain to debug when dealing with older python versions.